# How do I display user information from table 1 and 2 that don't exist in table 3?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a MySQL query that I am not quite sure how to create. Here is what I have in terms of tables and also what I want to accomplish with the query.

Table 1: **reg_worker**

- id
- name
- email

Table 2: **workers_reg_status**

- reg_id(same values as in table 1)
- status

Table 3: **is_editor**

- worker_id (same values as in table 1)

I would like to build a query that would select along the lines of:

```sql
SELECT
 reg_worker.id, reg_worker.name, reg_worker.email, workers_reg_status.status
FROM
 reg_worker, workers_reg_status
WHERE
     reg_workers.id = workers_reg_status.id 
 AND workers_reg_status.status = 1
 AND (/* reg_worker.id IS NOT ALREADY DEFINED IN is_editor.worker_id */)
```

How can I display user information from table 1 and 2 as long as they **are not** already registered in table 3?

This is what I have sofar:
I know I have to use NOT EXISTS in the query, but that's what I am having trouble with. Here is what I have so far (for clearity the sql query is splitted across multiple lines):

```
$sql_query = "SELECT 
              reg_workers.id, 
              reg_workers.first_name, 
              reg_workers.last_name, 
              reg_workers.date_registered, 
              reg_workers.email, 
              reg_workers.phone_number, 
              workers_reg_status.reg_status 
              FROM reg_workers,
                   workers_reg_status 
              FROM reg_workers, 
                   workers_reg_status 
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT worker_id 
                   FROM is_editor 
                   WHERE reg_workers.id = is_editor.worker_id) ";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use a NOT EXISTS clause

Comment: erm.... how this question is unclear? _"Basically, I want to display user information from table 1 and 2 AS LONG as they ARE NOT already registered in table 3."_ this clearly defines the question.

Comment: That's what I was asking myself. I admit the question is a bit long, but I needed to give a clear picture of the table structure.

Comment: Please take this question off hold: edits have been made to highlight the question being asked.